For the web with javascript, is it possible to style or customize the "Open file" dialog window to suite the style of our website application?
We have an html & javascript application with a button that opens a file dialog window allowing the user to select files. We would like the style the open file dialog interface window itself. Is this even a possibility? Instead of the standard square file open dialog window we want rounded corners and a blue background.
Searching google for javascript customize open file dialog did not return any relevant results.

AFAIK it's not possible. Will post an answer if I find a reputable source.

I can confirm that's not possible. The Open File dialog is controlled by the browser and OS.
